# Green, Red, Yellow, Cyan Lines Running Vertical On Laptop Screen? How Could I Fix It?

Tags: laptop, display, laptop-repair

I have a Toshiba Equium A200 laptop, and for the past 3 months thin lines have started to appear on the right hand side of the screen. It started with one red line, now there's a group of multicoloured lines on the right hand side (basically the full width of a scroll bar, as it covers it completely on this laptop) and another clump of multi coloured lines about an inch away from it.

I've read a few places, and most people say it's the GPU/Video Card that's broken. But I've plugged the laptop to an external monitor and these lines don't appear then, so I think it's safe to rule out that.

I have noticed that if I pull the top right corner of the screen towards me, some of them dissapear, so it's looking (to me) as the screen has gone.

The question I have, is that if it's the screen that's broken, is there any way I can fix it **without** replacing the screen panel. I have next to no money available to fix it, but I do need it for work etc.

Do any of you guys have a really clever way of fixing the issue? Even if it's temporary, or gets rid of half of the lines.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm making a guess here, but there's a very good chance that its the cable connecting the video card to the screen - when you pull it towards you, connections seem to be made/broken. If you could work out what sort of cable it is, and replace it, it *might* possibly solve the issue.

Comment: +1 because I've seen this type of problem on a few laptops over the years, and it always turned out to be a physical hardware problem.

Comment: +1.  This is almost certainly a hardware problem (if not the cable, the controller board or the LCD panel itself).

Comment: Probably the glassmount contacts that connect the drive electronics to the LCD panel - usually a tricky fix (kill or cure)

Comment: Thanks for the answers, when I get to a point I can take it a part I'll let you know how I get on.